# Win 2008 - "Pin to start menu" doesn't show up as a right-click option

Tags: windows-server-2008, start, windows

A couple of us in our organization have new VMs with Win 2008, and the "Pin to Start Menu" doesn't show up as an option when we right-click a program.   Also, the start menu is entirely empty.  Any ideas on how to get it working?

Comment: Are you logged in with temporary or mandatory profiles?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that, how/where can I check?  I am local admin on my VM.

Comment: Also, Visual Studio doesn't seem to remember the "Most recent" projects. So it would imply that we cannot save to our profile?

Comment: Is the server part of a Domain? Do you use Roaming Profiles? Run `%userprofile%` and see what directory comes up; if it says "TEMPn.xyz" then you've got a temporary profile; if the folder is your username check for a ntuser.man file (might be hidden/system).

Comment: It is my username.  There are some other ntuser files, but no ntuser.man.

Comment: Is the server part of a Domain? Did someone mess with the Default profile before these VMs were deployed? Sounds like a fubar profile, though it could be GPO if you're part of a Domain.

Comment: Yes, it is part of domain (should have said that earlier), and I'm logging on with Domain Account. I wouldn't be surprised if it is a Group Policy; but would like to know what to intelligent ask them to change.

Comment: There's so many possible settings in GPO that could screw it up, I wouldn't know where to start listing them. Whoever is in charge of GPO *should be* knowledgeable enough about the settings they've put in place to quickly identify the problem however. If this isn't the case, you may be out of luck until it's a priority for them to fix.